# Craft Commerce Missing Products Tab

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, commerce4

I've just installed the craft commerce plugin to trial it, but I'm not seeing the products tab under Commerce in the backend? Am I missing something? I'm using Craft 4.5.10.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Products* link in the navigation only shows up if you have at least one product type defined. Go to `Commerce` -> `System settings` -> `Product Types` to create your first product type.

Comment: Thanks, knew it was something simple!